# How can I pass shared data to threads in Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

sub test {
    my $s :shared = 22;
    my $thread = threads->new(\&thrsub);

    $thread->join();
    print $s;

}

sub thrsub {
    $s = 33;
}

test;
```

Why isn't the data being shared in the thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shares the variable, but you're accessing a different variable than the one you shared. (`use strict;` would have told you there were different variables in this case. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`) The fix is to use a single variable.

```
my $s :shared = 22;

sub test {
    my $thread = threads->new(\&thrsub);
    $thread->join();
    print $s;
}

sub thrsub {
    $s = 33;
}

test;
```

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstood what `threads::shared` does. It does not give access to variables across lexical scopes. If you want `thrsub` to affect `$s`, you'll have to pass a reference to it when you create the thread.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

sub test {
    my $s = 22;
    my $s_ref = share $s;
    my $thread = threads->new(\&thrsub, $s_ref);

    $thread->join();
    print $s;

}

sub thrsub {
    my $s_ref = shift;
    $$s_ref = 33;
    return;
}

test;
```